# How to build VSCode app bundle from source

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build VSCode from source on Mac, and make an app bundle. I tried following [these instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#packaging) which suggest you can run `gulp vscode-darwin` to package VSCode for Mac.

I tried that. It definitely compiles some stuff and it doesn't print any errors, but there's no `VSCode-darwin.app` anywhere. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh this is stupid. `gulp vscode-darwin` *does* build the app bundle, but it saves it in the *parent* directory. I.e. if you run `npx gulp vscode-darwin` in the root of the `vscode` repo, the output will be at `../VSCode-darwin`, not in `out`, `out-build`, `out-vscode`, or `.build` as you might expect.

Comment: how to build it for web?